# Setting up a trigger to watch new folders Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a logic app that will transfer files as they are created from my FTP server to my Azure file share. The structure of the folder my trigger is watching is structured by date (see below). Each day that a file is added, a new folder is created, so I need the trigger to check new subfolders but I don't want to go into the app every day to change which folder the trigger looks at. Is this possible?

Here's how my folder(Called data) structure is, each day that a file is added a new folder is created.

```
-DATA-

2016-10-01
2016-10-02
2016-10-03
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP Connector uses a configurable polling where you set how many times it should look for a file. The trigger currently does not support dynamic folders. However what you could try is the following:

- Trigger your logic app by recurrence (same principle as the FTP trigger in fact)
- Action: Create a variable to store the date time (format used in your folder naming)
- Action: Do a list files in folder (here you should be able to dynamically set the folder name using the variable you created)
- For-each file in folder

  - Action: Get File Content
  - Whatever you need to do with the file (call nested logic app in case you need to do multiple processing actions on each fiel is smart if you need to handle resubmits of the flow by file)

In order to avoid that you pick up every file each time, you will need to find a way to exlude files which have been processed in an earlier run. So either rename the file after it's processed to an extension you can exclude in the next run or move the file to a subfolder "Processed\datetime" in the root.

This solution will require more actions and thus will be more expensive. I haven't tried it out, but I think this should work. Or at least it's the approach I would try to set up.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Currently testing this, the only problem now is my condition doesn't work (IF AzureFileShare contains CurrentTime), so I'm not sure if the CurrentTime variable can be checked as a name. Unless I'm totally doing something wrong haha

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you're asking is not possible with the current FTP Connector.  And there aren't any really great solution right now...:(

As an aside, I've seen this pattern several times and, as you are seeing, it just causes more problems than it could solve, which realistically is 0. :)

If you own the FTP Server, the best thing to do is put the files in one folder.

If you do not own the FTP Server, politely mention to the owner that this patterns is causing problems and doesn't help you in any way so please, put the files on one folder ;)

Comment: Ahhh nooo! I read something that said this but it was posted years ago, I had hoped they fixed it :( I'm currently working on having multiple for each loops that just compare the files in each store and adds the ones that are missing, but we'll see if that actually works... Thanks for the input!

Comment: @AndrewBuikema This was a 'requested' feature on BizTalk for years and we still don't have it so waiting is not an option.